# How to make "cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option" a warnings with -Werror?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, command-line-arguments

I have a project that is using gcc 4.6.3, and am trying to migrate to 4.8.2. However, it needs to compile on 4.6 for a while. It is using `-Werror` with a few specific errors turned off. To use boost 1.55 with gcc 4.8, i needed to add `-Wno-unused-local-typedefs`. The problem is that with `-Werror`, gcc 4.6 emits this error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-local-typedefs" [-Werror]
```

The [gcc docs on warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) have no indication this particular warning can be treated explicitly as a warnings rather than an error. Is there any way to get 4.6 to treat this as a warning?

Comment: What is your buildsystem? Makefiles? CMake? Something else?

Comment: According to the docs (and confirmed with an experiment with gcc 4.6.4, which is the oldest gcc I have handy), the form `-Wno-unknown-warning` should not trigger an error even if `-Wunknown-warning` does. (Second paragraph after `-Wfatal-errors`, pretty close to the top of the page.) Exactly which version of `gcc` are you using?

Comment: Versions are 4.6.3 and 4.8.2. As per docs, -Wno-unknown-warning should not trigger an error... but appears to if -Werror is specified.

Comment: Apparently the docs are a bit more subtle than first glance will tell you -- the `-Wno-unknown-warning` form will only not cause a diagnostic if the compiler is not spitting out some *other* diagnostic message. (Same paragraph as @rici's comment)